# Get correct framerate from ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg

Good day,

I have a problem. I need to get correct framerate from ffmpeg libs..

I tried to use

```
pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->avg_frame_rate.num
```

return of avg_frame_rate is 2997. But when I dumped meta info, I got:

```
Input #0, avi, from '/test.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : MEncoder SVN-r33883(20110719-gcc4.5.2)
  Duration: 00:49:47.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1294 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 856x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 107:60], 1090 kb/s, SAR 491520:492521 DAR 8192:4603, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
2015-09-20 15:47:02.377 TV3[21607:769601] ready to start audio
```

sample rate is: 23.98fps. What value is correct and why are they different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, what's in `pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->avg_frame_rate.den`?

I bet it's `125` then. `AVStream::avg_frame_rate` is of type [`AVRational`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVRational.html), a structure holding a rational number as a fraction. To get a decimal value, you have to divide `num` by `den`.

`-> 2997 / 125 = 23.976`